# Prove that union of countable sets is countable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Could anyone explain to me the part in red? I can't see how the existence of the set T is used in the proof, and how theorem 2.8 is applied.

[image]

Here are the relevant definitions and theorem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Suppose the sequence of elements is $1,2,2,3,4,4,4,6,,,,,,,$, then to each element we assign a label, i.e. the first element is $1$, the second is $2$, the third is also $2$ and so on. But when you make up the set $S$, you won't be repeating elements. So $S$ will have number 1, number 2, number 4, number 5, number 8... and so on. So the set $T=\{1,2,4,5,8, \ldots\} \subset \Bbb{N}$ is in one-one correspondence with $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Following the arrows you get a surjective function $f:\mathbb N\to\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, but there might be repetitions, so it is not injective. Well then you just discard the duplicates and get a bijective function
$f:T\subseteq\mathbb N\to\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have in (17) is a function $g:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to S$. Namely, $g(k,j)=x_{k,j}$. You have that $g$ is surjective, but it may not be injective if there are elements repeated among the $E_n$.

Because $g$ is surjective, for each $s\in S$ there exists $(x_1,y_1)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ with $g(s_1,t_1)=s$. These pairs may not be unique if $g$ is not injective, but we may choose a single one for each $s$. Say $g(x_s,y_s)=s$. Now let 
$$
T=\{(x_s,y_s):\ s\in S\}.
$$
Then $S\sim T$ and $T\subset \mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. So $T$ is countable and $S$ is countable.

Comment: I was not talking about your answer, but rather the way it's phrased in the book, which might not be very clear for someone who is new to this.

Comment: Yes I agree that it is not sufficiently rigorous for something which should be quite pedagogical

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is a function from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow$ S, where $i \mapsto x_i$. This function is surjective by construction. Since there may be double counting, there is a subset T $\subset \mathbb{N}$ such that T $\sim$ S.